# Trying to find name of part for old kenmore oven

Tags: gas, oven

I have a part that is getting worn and needs to be replaced. Does anyone know what the name is for this part? It's in an old Kenmore gas oven, model 911.7313191. It's at the bottom of the oven, a large grey flat part with slots cut into it. It lifts out easily. See picture. I have the owner's manual but this part doesn't seem to be included in the schematic.

[image]

Comment: I see it on the [Sears parts engine](https://www.searspartsdirect.com/model-number/9117313191/0582/0124200.html?searchType=modelSearch&q=911.7313191&searchTerm=911.7313191) , but it doesn’t look like it’s still orderable from Sears.  Your options are to find a used appliance dealer that has a used one on hand.

Comment: Thanks, it's at least 20 years old so I guess not surprising that parts not available easily.